# How to open a video using openCV in java and extract all frames from it

Tags: java, opencv

I am doing a project in which I have to extract frames from the video and process it. I have completed the part of processing frames. Now I need to get all the frames from a video. I am using openCV + java for my project. I have tried the following code but it didn't work.

```
package com.cooltrickshome;

import org.opencv.core.Mat;
import org.opencv.imgcodecs.Imgcodecs;
import org.opencv.videoio.VideoCapture;

public class Frames {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.load("/home/opencv_build/build/lib/libopencv_java460.so");

        String mp4Path = "/home/test/input.mp4";

        VideoCapture cap = new VideoCapture();

        cap.open(mp4Path);
        Mat frame = new Mat();
        int i = 1;
        if (cap.isOpened()) {
            System.out.println("Success 1 ::::");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Failed 1 :::::");
        }
        while (cap.isOpened()) {
            cap.read(frame);
            if (Imgcodecs.imwrite("/home/test/frame" + i + ".jpg", frame)) {
                System.out.println("Success ::::");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Failed :::::");
            }
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

The output of this code is 'Failed 1 ::::' which indicates video is not opened. Can anyone tell me what went wrong in my code ? Or suggest any alternate solution to extract the frames ?